# Turning a long string into a paragraph in console in Java without creating manually(means not using \n for new line)

Tags: java

In Java, I want to print a rather long String to the console, but instead of having it printed as one really long line, I'd like to turn it into a nicely formatted paragraph and if I change the size of console then String will adjust accordingly

Comment: Please post what you have tried yourself.

Comment: Java doesn't provide this kind of functionality, it's console support is pretty basic.  You might have a look at a Curses implementation, but I'm not sure that would suffice

Comment: This isn't normally how the Java console is implemented. You don't normally have this kind of control or ability to respond to changes in the console window. The nearest I can offer is opening a GUI window and using a suitable layout.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an IDE they often have console preferences you can set for standard output. For example, in Eclipse you can set [fixed width console](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Frun-debug%2Fref-console.htm) to wrap text automatically.

If this is not an option with your console, then you can use a function like this on this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20802808/java-string-new-line-loop) (see function supplied by @azordi)   to add \n at the positions you require for your console. Essentially uses a loop to add the line break character every specified length. The contract with the function is you supply the string to have line breaks added, the length as an int you want them added and the function returns a string with the line breaks added that you can pass to standard output System.out.printf().